# asp.net mvc parameter binding string and guid

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a webapi controller with the following method signature:

```
        public IHttpActionResult GetAttractions([FromUri] SearchAttractionRequest request)
```

The class SearchAttractionRequest looks like:

```
    public class SearchAttractionRequest
{
    public string Region { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }

    public string Genre { get; set; }

}
```

This all works fine.

I am looking to create a new endpoint with same but this time the parameter will have fields that are guids so it will look like:

```
    public class SearchAttractionGuidRequest
{
    public Guid? Region { get; set; }

    public Guid? Category { get; set; }

    public Guid? Genre { get; set; }

}
```

And the new endpoint will be :

```
        public IHttpActionResult GetAttractions([FromUri] SearchAttractionGuidRequest request)
```

Given that the parameters are coming from query string would the binding be able to bind?  At the querystring level it's all strings.  Ideally, I want to avoid creating a method with a new name.

Currently when i try this i get:

> Multiple actions were found that match the request: GetAttractions

Comment: change the order of routes in the route configuration this line should be first config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( "DefaultApiWithAction", "Api/{controller}/{action}" );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid creating a new method name by specifying different [Route] attributes for those methods.